# exe file created by pyinstaller (python 3.5)

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I would like to prove the file that I have created by pyinstaller but I have one doubt: must I copy only the exe file to the new computer (that hasn't python and all the libraries) or must I bring there also all the folders generated by pyinstaller (that are "dist" and "setup") to install the application and all the dependencies easily in other computers?

I created the exe file in this way:

```
pyinstaller --onefile setup.py
```

Answer (score 0):

PyInstaller is a program that freezes (packages) Python programs into stand-alone executables, under Windows, Linux or Mac, Its main advantages over similar tools are that PyInstaller works with Python 2.7 and 3.3—3.5, it builds smaller executables thanks to transparent compression, it is fully multi-platform, and use the OS support to load the dynamic libraries, thus ensuring full compatibility.

-->It Executes Packaging of Python programs into standard executables, that work on computers without Python installed.

Comment: So i have copied from windows all the folders generated by pyinstaller and I have pasted them in the desktop of one ubuntu virtual machine. Now how may I launch the application in ubuntu?